# Getting all unused variables in an XSL stylesheet

Tags: xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to create an XPath expression that will give me all unused variables in an XSL stylesheet and the preceding text node, if it is whitespace-only.

My current try is this:

`for $var in //xsl:variable|xsl:param return($var[not(following-sibling::*/descendant-or-self::*[@*[contains(., concat('$', $var/@name))]])]/(., preceding-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.) = '']))`

However, since I rely on the `contains()` function to get the variables, I also get false negatives, e.g.

`<xsl:variable name="abc"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$abcdef"/>`

What would be the best way to solve this? I suppose regex must be used for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this rigorously, you need to understand the variable binding rules in full detail. For example, given:

```
<xsl:template match="x">
  <xsl:variable name="y"/>
  <xsl:variable name="y"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$y"/>
</xsl:template>
```

then the first "y" variable is unused.

It's complicated by the fact that you can have forwards references to global variables, but not to local variables.

Also, if you want to be really rigorous, then you need to handle the fact that variable names can be namespace qualified, and the matching of names uses namespace URIs, not prefixes.

And what about references appearing in commented-out code, for example?

And it's not widely known that you're allowed to have whitespace and comments between the '$' and the name in a variable reference:

`$ (:no-one ever does this:) x + $ (:thankfully:) y`

So, a first cut that simply detects names of variables that are declared but never appear in a variable reference isn't too difficult; a rigorous solution that gives no false positives and no false negatives requires access to the complete parse tree of the stylesheet and its XPath expressions. The difficulty here is that with the obvious ways of getting such a parse tree (e.g. Saxon's SEF export file) the unused variables will already have been discarded.

What is the purpose of the exercise: how do you intend to use the results?

Comment: Thanks for your insightful response. I have inherited a bunch of stylesheets that were poorly maintained over the years. Since the input XML vocabulary has changed, the code needs to be changed (and cleaned up) too, and it would help me if code that no longer serves a purpose is removed. It definitely does not need to be waterproof, one may assume that namespaces, whitespace, comments,... are no issue here and that variables will only be used in their regular form.

Comment: To add to this: a global variable may not be referenced in the xslt stylesheet that declares it, but at the same time it may be referenced in other xslt stylesheets that import or include the declaring stylesheet. So, deciding that this variable is "not used" and deleting it may have unexpected results: when attempting to run a number of transformations, there would appear compilation errors for not being able to find this variable. The worst thing is that any such error may not appear immediately and could happen ages after the removal of the variable

Answer (score 0):

A basic attempt to find and remove unused variables in templates might be as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mine="http://mine"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="3.0">

  <!-- baseline identity transform -->
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <!-- delete variable definitions that are not subsequently referenced -->
  <xsl:template match="*
    [mine:is-unreferenced-variable(.)]"/>
  <xsl:template match="text()
    [matches(., '^\s*\n\s*$')]
    [following-sibling::node()[1]
      [mine:is-unreferenced-variable(.)]]"/>  <!-- (and preceding whitespace) -->


  <!-- create an accessor function to the mode="is-unreferenced-variable" templates -->
  <xsl:function name="mine:is-unreferenced-variable" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="v" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$v" mode="is-unreferenced-variable"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <!-- default -->
  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="is-unreferenced-variable">
    <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- assume variable definitions are unreferenced unless proven otherwise -->
  <xsl:template match="xsl:template//xsl:variable" mode="is-unreferenced-variable">
    <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- keep variables referenced in subsequent attribute values -->
  <xsl:template match="xsl:template//xsl:variable
    [following-sibling::*//@*[matches(., '\$\s*' || current()/@name || '\b', ';j')]]" mode="is-unreferenced-variable">
    <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- keep variables referenced in subsequent text value templates -->
  <xsl:template match="xsl:template//xsl:variable
    [following-sibling::*//text()[matches(., '\{.*' || '\$\s*' || current()/@name || '\b' || '.*\}', ';j')]]" mode="is-unreferenced-variable">
    <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This implements a very simple heuristic that removes any variable that is not referenced by some node in its following scope. It considers attribute values and text nodes (for template ), but it ignores comments.

It does not handle the possibility of comments inside variable references as Michael mentioned, but this could be handled with an additional `replace()`.

The heuristic is simple and can certainly be fooled. The results require manual inspection for correctness. Still, it's something to work with for large stylesheet sets.

Feel free to suggest improvements!

P.S. This could have been simplified to the following:

```
<!-- delete variable definitions that are not subsequently referenced -->
<xsl:template match="xsl:template//xsl:variable
  [not(
    following-sibling::*//(
      @*[matches(., '\$\s*' || current()/@name || '\b', ';j')] |
      text()[matches(., '\{.*' || '\$\s*' || current()/@name || '\b' || '.*\}', ';j')]
    )
  )]"/>
```

but I find the template-based method easier to extend to handle corner cases.